# How can I transform the Object in this Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript

Given this array of objects:

```
arrayBefore: [
        {
            a: "string1",
            b: 10,
        },
        {
            a: "string2",
            b: 20,
        },
]
```

how can one change the keys using JavaScript for the end result of:

```
arrayAfter: [
        {
            x: "string1",
            y: 10,
        },
        {
            x: "string2",
            y: 20,
        },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the objects.

```js
const arrayBefore = [{
    a: "string1",
    b: 10,
  },
  {
    a: "string2",
    b: 20,
  },
]

const arrayAfter = arrayBefore.map((item) => ({
  x: item.a,
  y: item.b,
}))

console.log(arrayAfter)
```